# Replace axis labels with custom in highcharts r

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, r-highcharter

How can I put letters on the yaxis axis labels?

I want the yaxis labels to be (a,e,i,o,u) instead of (0,25,50,75,100), but I'm getting (a,25,50,75,100)

I'm trying the following

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type="bar",zoomType="x") %>%
  hc_yAxis(
    categories = c("a","e","i","o","u"),
    title='',
    tickInterval=25,
    min=0,
    max=100)%>%   
...
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the issue, the `categories` in `hc_yAxis` is assigned sequentially, so in your case it will replace from `0` to `5` (including). You can hack this with `seq` and replace.

```
categories_list <- list("0"="a","25"="e","50"="i","75"="o","100"="u")
categories <- seq(0, 100)

for (v in names(categories_list)) {
  categories[[as.integer(v) + 1]] <- categories_list[[v]]
}

highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Tokyo", data = citytemp$tokyo) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "New York", data = citytemp$new_york) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Berlin", data = citytemp$berlin) %>% 
  hc_chart(type="bar",zoomType="x") %>%
  hc_yAxis(
    categories = categories,
    title='',
    tickInterval=25,
    min=0,
    max=100)
```

And the result:

[image]